# Is determinism equivalent to necessitarianism? If not, does one imply the other?

Tags: determinism, necessity

I am having a hard time understanding the difference between determinism and necessitarianism. What is the difference between them? Are they equivalent, or is one strictly stronger than the other, or do neither of them imply the other?

Comment: Necessitarianism is usually understood to be stronger than determinism. In determinism, from a given starting point only one course follows. It is like an equation with only one solution, but the equation has boundary conditions. In necessitarianism, there is only one way the universe as a whole could possibly be. It is like an equation with one solution and no boundary conditions, or where all the boundary conditions are specified and immutable. However, some dictionaries seem to think they are synonymous.

Comment: I agree with Bumble's point, but there is also a sense in which (hard) determinism is more specific than necessitarianism. Necessitarianism asserts that the world is the only way it can be... for some reason or none. Determinism asserts that it is so, given the initial state, *because of physical laws*. That last part is not specified by necessitarianism. So, in the end, neither of them implies the other.